# Which Hadoop to use for Mahout 0.9

Tags: hadoop, mahout

I'm using Mahout Cookbook, which shows examples for Mahout 0.8 and uses Hadoop 0.23.5.

I'm new to the whole system, so I would like to know which Hadoop version to use when running Mahout 0.9?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When pulling Mahout 0.9 from maven it includes hadoop-core version 1.2.1. Mahout version 0.9 does not work with hadoop 2 according to [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-1329). It is resolved in the latest [master](https://github.com/apache/mahout) branch on github, but this requires you to recompile mahout from the source and include the hadoop 2 libraries. Mahout 1.0 should support hadoop 2.X versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to run Mahout 0.9 with Hadoop 2, you can follow these steps to make it work:

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/mahout.git
```

In the Mahout folder, type:

```
mvn -Dhadoop2.version=2.2.0 -DskipTests clean install
mvn -Dhadoop2.version=2.2.0 clean package
```

And below is a usage example for recommenditembased:

```
bin/mahout recommenditembased  --input input/input.txt --output output --usersFile input/users.txt --similarityClassname SIMILARITY_COOCCURRENCE
```

Edit: original source is http://mahout.apache.org/developers/buildingmahout.html

Answer (score 0):

This version of Mahout also runs with hadoop 0.2 core jar. 
I am using it on windows machine , as 0.2 onwards, hadoop gives permission exception for windows system